# Automatically Filing Chrome (Mac) Downloads By Source

Tags: mac, google-chrome, file-management

Is there a way on the Mac (Chrome extension, Mac app, script, or otherwise) to automatically file Chrome downloads into folders by source / website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rules this with [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php):

[image]

Or run shell commands like this manually or with [launchd](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40705):

`for f in ~/Downloads/*; do mdls -raw -n kMDItemWhereFroms "$f" | grep -q example.com && mv "$f" ~/Movies; done`

Comment: This seems to be working. I put the shell command into an automator folder action. Thank you for the help!